# Remove $ from a column of salaries python 3

Tags: python-3.5

I am trying to print the min and max from a list of salaries that I am reading from a csv file, but first I must remove the $ from the value and don't know how.

I tried iterating through the list and using `del[0]` and got:

> SyntaxError: can't delete literal.

I tried `salary.replace("$", " ")` and got:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

I appended the salaries column to a list which is an immutable string.

How would I remove the $ from a salary list that looks like [$98,500.85]?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post your code around that line?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know the exact problem without the code, but you could try one of these:

```
new_salary = [s.replace("$", "") for s in salary]
```

or:

```
new_salary = [s[1:] for s in salary]
```